# Checkout with custom Address attributes in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, checkout

I have a ”District” attribute created to my Customer_Address because my shipping is calculated base on it.
This attribute shows perfectly well in my checkout and the user can select from a couple of options with no problem.

However when it checksout, the collectRates() method in my class receives a ”Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request” with some information about the options selected by the user to checkout.
At this point, I need to have a way to get whatever the user has set as the District value to calculate the shipping cost based on that, but I can’t seem to get the information from Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request.

Is there a way I can add the attribute to that class to retrieve it later?
or
Should I be looking to get that value in some other way?

Whatever help you can give me will be very useful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you solved this already...

Anyway, I had the same problem and solved it this way:

Rewrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` and `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping`, these are the classes that do `$request = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request');`

So it looks like:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address{

public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
{
    /** @var $request Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request */
    $request = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request');

    // add custom attribute
    $request->setDestCustom($this->getCustomAddressAttribute());
    ...
}
}
```

and

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping{

    public function collectRatesByAddress(Varien_Object $address, $limitCarrier = null)
    {
        /** @var $request Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request */
        $request = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request');
        ...

        // add custom attribute
        $request->setDestCustom($address->getCustomAddressAttribute());
     }
}
```